# Referenced equation numbers not shown in unreferenced equations

Tags: cross-referencing, mathtools

I like very much the `mathtools` option `showonlyrefs` which allows that labels of an equation are displayed only, if there is a reference to the equation.
The problem is, that references in an equation are supressed, if the equation has a label that is never referred. The following MWE is more understandable:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\mathtoolsset{showonlyrefs}

\begin{document}

CASE A: equation with reference has no label
\begin{equation}
    1 = 1 \label{eq1a}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation} 
    1 = 1 \qquad \text{(see \eqref{eq1a})}
\end{equation}

\hrulefill

CASE B: equation with reference has label and is referenced itself \eqref{eq2b}
\begin{equation}
    1 = 1 \label{eq1b}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation} \label{eq2b}
    1 = 1 \qquad \text{(see \eqref{eq1b})}
\end{equation}

\hrulefill

CASE C: equation with reference has label but is not referenced itself
\begin{equation}
    1 = 1 \label{eq1c}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation} \label{eq2c}
    1 = 1 \qquad \text{(see \eqref{eq1c})}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Which produces (after enough compilation runs)

[image: output of mwe]

Case A and B behave like expected, in case C however there is no reference (4).

While it is easy to find a workaround (just delete the label) if there is no reference to the equation, I would prefer to have a automatic solution.

Comment: Even though the name invites you to do so, don't use `minimal` for minimal examples.

Comment: @Johannes_B Thanks for the hint, with article the problem is the same, I will update the MWE

Comment: i tried it with `amsart` both with multiple `equation`s and with `gather`.  all with the same result.  looks like a bug to me.

Comment: @barbarabeeton OK, I will write a bug report to the maintainer of the mathtools package.

Comment: @barbarabeeton, see my answer below. If interested the problem tracks down to `\MT_extended_maketag:n`.

Comment: @daleif -- thanks for explanation.  i'll take a closer look when i'm back in the office.  (i'm on an island at the moment, looking out over a marsh and listening to bird songs.  just checking in to try to keep the waiting pile from being overwhelming when i get back.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton, not need. It was only if you  were curious. The best solution will be to patch the extended eqref

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is recommended to use

```
\mathtoolsset{showonlyrefs,showmanualtags}
```

whenever you use `showonlyrefs`

I'm not quite sure what the best solution is to avoid having to add `showmanualtags` (the original author always recommended using both).

---

The problem here ends up in the internal logic. The `showonlyrefs` feature hooks into the *typesetting* of the equation number. This is used in two places:

1. typesetting the equation number in the displayed math, *and*
2. in `\eqref`

The problem here is that `\eqref` is actually being used inside a displayed math env, and thus ends up testing against the env label and not the given label.

Issuing `showmanualtags` circumvents this.

---

An even better solution might be to simply patch the `\eqref` version being used when `showonlyrefs` is active, using this:

```
\MHInternalSyntaxOn
\def\MT_extended_eqref:n #1{
  \protected@write\@auxout{}
  {\string\MT@newlabel{#1}}
  \textup{\let\df@label\@empty\MT_prev_tagform:n {\ref{#1}}}
}
\MHInternalSyntaxOff
```

The trick is the emptying of `\df@label` when ever the tagform is being used in a `\eqref` context.

I think I'll add this to the next `mathtools` release.